# Visual Studio cannot connect to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, freetds

Getting a message "login failed for user [my_user]"

Of note is that I am capable of connecting to the server with freetds from linux using the same server, username and password and TDS protocol 7.4. The port is the default SQL Server port. Viz. `$tsql -S [my_server] -U "my_user" -P "my_pass"` succeeds and I am able to poke around in the server.

However, on my windows machine, it simply reports that my login has failed.

- Data Source: Microsoft SQL Server
- Server Name: [my_server]
- Use SQL Server Authentication: User name: [my_user] Password: [my_pass]

Any thoughts on what to try?

**UPDATE:**

I can connect via pymssql with

```
pymssql.connect(server=[my_server], user=[my_user], password=[my_pass])
```

Comment: Make sure you really are connecting to the same server from both machines. See if DNS or `hosts` file are not messing you up.